# Popup from datepicker showing wrong year

Tags: c#, angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker

The popup from the datepicker in angular is showing the wrong year when opened. However the year after December 2011 is changing to 2021 as it should be from the beginning.

I am using Angular 12.2.0 with Bootstrap 4.3.1. I cant figure out how to change this.. Maybe compatibility issues? Sorry I can only link the image because of "reputation points" :P

[Datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNM1O.png)

date-picker.component.html

```
 <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <input class="form-control" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (change)="onDateChange($event.target.value)" (dateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)" [disabled]="isDisabled ? 'disabled' : null">
  <div class="input-group-append" *ngIf="!isDisabled">
    <button class="btn btn-input calendar fa fa-calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

date-picker.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, forwardRef, Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateParser } from '../../ngb-date-parser';
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDatepickerI18n, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, } from '@angular/forms';

const I18N_VALUES = {
  'it-IT': {
    weekdays: ['Lu', 'Ma', 'Me', 'Go', 'Ve', 'Sa', 'Do'],
    months: ['Gen', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mag', 'Giu', 'Lug', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Ott', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
  },
  'de-DE': {
    weekdays: ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'],
    months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  },
  'en-US': {
    weekdays: ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'],
    months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  },
  'en-UK': {
    weekdays: ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'],
    months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  }
};

@Injectable()
export class I18n {
  language = localStorage.getItem('locale');
}

// Define custom service providing the months and weekdays translations
@Injectable()
export class CustomDatepickerI18n extends NgbDatepickerI18n {

  constructor(private i18n: I18n) {
    super();
  }

  getWeekdayShortName(weekday: number): string {
    return I18N_VALUES[this.i18n.language].weekdays[weekday - 1];
  }
  getMonthShortName(month: number): string {
    return I18N_VALUES[this.i18n.language].months[month - 1];
  }
  getMonthFullName(month: number): string {
    return this.getMonthShortName(month);
  }
  getDayAriaLabel(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    return `${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}`;
  }
}


export const DATEPICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR =  {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],  
  providers: [DATEPICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateParser}, 
              I18n, {provide: NgbDatepickerI18n, useClass: CustomDatepickerI18n}]

})

export class DatePickerComponent  implements ControlValueAccessor {
  selectedDate: any;
  isDisabled = false;
  @Output() dateChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {}

  // Function to call when the date changes.
  onChange = (date?: Date) => {

  };

  // Function to call when the date picker is touched
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value: Date) {
    if (!value) {
      this.selectedDate = undefined;
      return;
    }

    value = new Date(value);
    this.selectedDate = {
      year: value.getFullYear(),
      month: value.getMonth()+1,
      day: value.getDate()
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (date: Date) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the input has been touched.
  // Save the function as a property to call later here.
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  // Allows Angular to disable the input.
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  // Write change back to parent
  onDateChange(value: string) {
    const dateString = value.split('.');
    if(dateString.length == 3) {    
      const date: Date = new Date(+dateString[2], +dateString[1]-1, +dateString[0]);
      this.onChange(date);
    } 
    if (value == null || value == '') {
      this.onChange(null);
    }
  }

  // Write change back to parent
  onDateSelect(value: any) {
    this.onChange(new Date(value.year, value.month - 1, value.day));
    this.dateChange.emit(value);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-bootstrap was outdated. An update to 10.0.0 was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not quite sure why it would be defaulting to 2011.

But, until a better answer is provided, according to the ngb-datepicker documentation (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview, section titled Content Template), you can provide

`[startDate] = "{month: {month}, year: {year}"`

to the html component tag. Perhaps you can use this in the meantime to manually make sure the year is the current year.

Comment: I noticed when using your workaround that the year is always 10 years less then what I write in [startDate]. For example if I use the year 2000 then the popup shows 1990.

Thats the reason it shows 2011 (2021 - 10). Strange behavior.

Comment: Very strange, yeah I guess then a workaround for now would be getting the current year and adding 10 to it lol, not ideal. I wonder if you were to, in an empty project, reconstruct your date picker and see if the issue still persists. Then, slowly make changes to it, and as you add each thing you've got, test it out and see if/where the date goes back ten years.